# Convert a text file into table using Python

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this

```
client interface: GigabitEthernet10/0/0.100 is up
active state: up
line state: up
vc state: down
...
colour: -

client interface: EthTrunk10.0.1 is up
active state: up
line state: up
vc state: down
...
colour: -
```

The list can go very long with around 5000-10000 lines of text

Any better idea to convert it to a table form like below?

```
Client Interface           Active State    Line State    VC State    ...     Color
GigabitEthernet10/0/0.100     up              up           down                 -
EthTrunk10.0.1                up              up           down                 -
```

Comment: Are you asking for how to convert the first text block to the second? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: try to read all lines and split by `:` for each column and value as like: `column, value = line.split(':')` except for interface name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import in pandas use like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.txt", sep=":", header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming You know the number of columns per interface:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('text_filename.txt', sep=':', header=None)
N_COLS = 5

table_data = df.iloc[:,1].values.reshape(-1, N_COLS)
table_header = df.iloc[:n_cols,0].values

df = pd.DataFrame(table_data, columns=table_header)
```

Output:

```
               client interface active state line state vc state colour
0   GigabitEthernet10/0/0.100 is up           up         up     down      -
1              EthTrunk10.0.1 is up           up         up     down      -
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for. Since, I don't know the exact amount of things each interface contains, I found headers first and then looped inside.

```
import pandas as pd
with open("sample.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [l.strip() for l in lines]
n = len(lines)
headers = set()
for i in range(n):
    if(len(lines[i])>=3):
        key, value = lines[i].split(":")
        headers.add(key)
hlen = len(headers)
completeList = list()
for i in range(0,n,hlen):
    dictrow = dict()
    for j in range(hlen):
        if(j+i<n and len(lines[j+i])>=3):
            key,value = lines[j+i].split(":")
            dictrow[key] = value
    completeList.append(dictrow)
    dictrow = dict()
df = pd.DataFrame(completeList)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Pandas**

```
import re

# Pattern for recognizing category and value
pattern = re.compile(r'^(\w+ \w+): (\S+)')

details = {}
with open('data.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        res = pattern.match(line)
        label = res.group(1).title()   # category 
        value = res.group(2)           # value
        details.setdefault(label, []).append(value)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

**Data Frame**

```
    Client Interface                  Active State  Line State  Vc State
0   GigabitEthernet10/0/0.100         up            up          down
1   EthTrunk10.0.1                    up            up          down
```